# overloading operator < for std::set confused me

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, set, std

I know that I have to overload operator < for std::set.

I overload operator < with two classes: "UniqueID" and "UniqueIDWithBug".
The only difference is "UniqueID" added code `this->unique_id_a_ == t.unique_id_a_` while comparing.

Then I put same elements into the two sets.
Finally I find one element inside the sets.
One set can find it, another can not.
This problem confused me for a long time.

```
struct UniqueID {
    uint64_t unique_id_a_{0};
    uint64_t unique_id_b_{0};

    bool operator<(const UniqueID &t) const {
        if (this->unique_id_a_ < t.unique_id_a_) {
            return true;
        }
        if (this->unique_id_a_ == t.unique_id_a_ &&
            this->unique_id_b_ < t.unique_id_b_) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

struct UniqueIDWithBug {
    uint64_t unique_id_a_{0};
    uint64_t unique_id_b_{0};

    bool operator<(const UniqueIDWithBug &t) const {
        if (this->unique_id_a_ < t.unique_id_a_) {
            return true;
        }
        return (this->unique_id_b_ < t.unique_id_b_);
    }
};

// init data
std::set<UniqueID> _set = {
        {17303934402126834534u, 2922971136},
        {8520106912500150839u,  3118989312},
        {9527597377742531532u,  2171470080},
        {10912468396223017462u, 3972792320},
};
std::set<UniqueIDWithBug> _set_with_bug = {
        {17303934402126834534u, 2922971136},
        {8520106912500150839u,  3118989312},
        {9527597377742531532u,  2171470080},
        {10912468396223017462u, 3972792320}};

UniqueID _unique_id = {10912468396223017462u, 3972792320};
UniqueIDWithBug _unique_id_with_bug = {10912468396223017462u, 3972792320};

if (_set.find(_unique_id) == _set.end()) {
    std::cout << "_set not find" << std::endl;
}

if (_set_with_bug.find(_unique_id_with_bug) == _set_with_bug.end()) {
    std::cout << "_set_with_bug not find" << std::endl;
}
```

The outputs:
_set_with_bug not find

Comment: Yes, `UniqueIDWithBug` is wrong. So what exactly are you asking. Something fundamental is missing from your question. That would be an actual, specific question.

Comment: I confused why UniqueIDWithBug is wrong, I think operator < for UniqueIDWithBug  is enough

Comment: Trace and compare `UniqueIDWithBug a{1, 10}` and `UniqueIDWithBug b{2,5}`. Doing `a < b` and `b < a` both return `true`. So how can an ordering be defined?

Comment: Consider using an [`unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)?

Comment: The faulty version of your code does not handle the situation where `this->unique_id_a > t.unique_id_a`. The first version returns `false`, regardless of the values of `unique_id_b`. The second version may return `true` or `false`, depending on what values `unique_id_b` have.This may break the strict ordering and therefore return arbitrary results

Comment: `std::tie` makes doing this correctly much easier. `return std::tie(unique_id_a_, unique_id_b_) < std::tie(t.unique_id_a_, t.unique_id_b_);` is all you need in your `operator<`. Imagine extending your correct version to handle 4 variables manually.

Answer (score 5):

The less-than operation you define for use with `std::set` (and others) must be a valid *strict weak ordering*.

Your *UniqueIDWithBug* ordering is not.

For example, consider:

```
UniqueIDWithBug a{1, 10};
UniqueIDWithBug b{2, 5};
```

Now observe that both `a < b` and `b < a` are true. This is just a quick demonstration that you do not have a strict weak ordering; indeed, this is not an ordering at all!

So your program has undefined behaviour. The internals of the `std::set` mechanism assume a valid ordering, but yours is not. In this case the observable result was "element not found". It could have been "make a pizza".

Constructing a good strict weak ordering can be difficult, but you've already done the hard work, because *UniqueID*'s ordering is correct.

Alternatively, abandon the ordering entirely, define a hash function, and switch to `unordered_set`.